# react-native : image-crop-picker onPress cancel

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) and want to know how to setState when `cancel button is pressed`. Is there a way I could call a function when `cancel button` is pressed?

Comment: the native does not handle this event if you want to this, you have to modify the codes. if you want how to do it in the android, I can give an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setState in the .catch method as openPicker returns a promise.

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  cropping: true
}).then(image => {
  // Here you handle the image 
}).catch(err => {
 // Here you handle if the user cancels or any other errors
})
```

Answer (score -2):

May be you can handle using checking that image is selected or not.

```js
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  cropping: true
}).then(image => {
  if (image) {
    // Image is selected
  } else {
    // Cancel Pressed
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. but I don't think the code inside else would be equal to pressing cancel button.